# Why can't I stop Solr from running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

The [sunspot_solr](https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot_solr) version that I am using is 1.3.3.

I am using [sunspot_solr gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sunspot_solr) to start and stop a local instance of Solr. I use the following command to start it:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

and the following command to stop it:

```
rake sunspot:solr:stop
```

However, stop is not working. I noticed that the pid written in the pids folder is not the correct one.

When I start, I can see the following as output on the `ps -ef | grep 'java'` command:

```
1000      4758  4752  0 20:32 ?        00:00:00 sh -c java -Djetty.port\=8982 -Dsolr.data.dir\=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home\=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file\=/tmp/logging.properties20120902-4758-13patuu -jar start.jar

1000      4761  4758  7 20:32 ?        00:00:01 java -Djetty.port=8982 -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties20120902-4758-13patuu -jar start.jar
```

This means that the real server process is the one with pid "4761". Process "4758" is only there to start the server in a shell.

When I cat the pid file I see:

```
cat solr/pids/development/sunspot-solr-development.pid
4758
```

Which means that `rake sunspot:solr:stop` is killing "4758" and leaves "4761" up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downgraded to `'sunspot_solr', '1.3.1'` and now it works ok.

Answer (score 3):

it's a bug!

```
1000      4758  4752  0 20:32 ?        00:00:00 sh -c java -Djetty.port\=8982 -    Dsolr.data.dir\=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home\=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file\=/tmp/logging.properties20120902-4758-13patuu -jar start.jar

1000      4761  4758  7 20:32 ?        00:00:01 java -Djetty.port=8982 -Dsolr.data.dir=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr/data/development -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/panayotis/my_documents/ezMTA/solr -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties20120902-4758-13patuu -jar start.jar
```

because process 4758 is a foreground process, but process 4761 is a background process,so if you kill pid 4758,it will not destroy his child process 4761, the init process will become process 4761's parent!

in sunspot_solr/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb #line 103

```
exec(Shellwords.shelljoin(command))
```

Shellwords.shelljoin(command) is a string,but [Kernel#exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) descrip:

```
exec([env,] command... [,options])
```

If single string is given as the command, it is taken as a command line that is subject to shell expansion before being executed.The standard shell means always "/bin/sh" on Unix-like systems.

so,it will start two process.

use this:
exec(*command)

will start one process,so rake sunspot:solr:stop will work correct.

[see this pull request](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/221)

Answer (score -1):

Set env like this - `RAILS_ENV=production rake sunspot:solr:stop`